# C/C++ offset of a structure member

Tags: c++, c, struct, casting

I have been looking tor sources, and i found a macro which is defined like so :

```
#define STRUCT_OFFSET(tp, member) \
   ((off_t) (((char*)&((tp*)0)->member)-(char*)0))
```

I looked up the `off_t` and it is just typedef for `long`, so it is the basic length of the pointer variable in the end. But what with this conversion?
`((char*)&((tp*)0)`

What does this even suppose to mean, why is there a zero? Also how does  this part even works out `(char*)0` , casting a zero (NULL) to the pointer to (NULL)? Suppose it if i do without a macro, i cant just do someting like `int offset = &MyStruct::some_member;` Is this possible to do without macro?

Comment: Don't use that macro, use the compiler-supplied `offsetof()`.

Comment: @EOF i curious, what does this part suppose to achieve `-(char*)0)` substracting a zero pointer?

Comment: It achieves undefined behavior.

Comment: @yasofiz - Yes it is using null pointers and is illegal to use (undefined behavior). *However*, for a specific compiler it might be implementation defined and actually work. That's why it just *might* be used in the `offsetof` macro of the compiler's standard library.

Comment: @BoPersson let me check if i understood, so on some compilers this code will take the structure, and the virtual address in program at offset 0. On some compilers the structure is getting mapped to that address, and the `&((tp*)0)->member);` will get the offset of a member, from the base zero address, withoud dereferencing the member itself?

Comment: @yasofiz: On conforming implementations, the code may take the value of elephant, subtract the kitchen sink, format the harddisks and return a volleyball.

Comment: @EOF yes right... Was just strange to me too see something like that for first time. This macro is used to allocate a space for structure, i was thinking, why they don't just use `sizeof`..

Comment: Well, `offsetof` is obviously the wrong operator to allocate space for anything. I suspect you may not learn much of value from whatever code used this.

Comment: @yasofiz - Some code in the standard library might **not** be conforming to the language standard. It can be so, because it is only required to work with its companion compiler. The guys writing the library can make a deal with the compiler team to make it work. Sometimes this results in a magic function `__builtin_offsetof()`, sometimes a guarantee that `&*pointer` will result in `pointer` even for NULL. [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) in particular is tricky, because it cannot be written "properly". It needs some support from the compiler.

Comment: @BoPersson: `&*(char*)NULL` is well-defined. `&((char*)NULL)->foo` is not.